# Mac mini-hosted WordPress websites won't load on any of the Macs on LAN

Tags: network, mac-mini, dns, router, webserver

I have three Mac minis on our LAN, all of which have Yosemite and OS X Server, but only one is enabled as a web server. My problem is that I can see the WordPress-based websites hosted on this web server externally, and on all the Windows machines on our LAN, but not on ANY of the Macs on our LAN.

One of our company's most important applications is based on being able to have one of the Macs query the webserver with http_get from time to time, and lately this query gets timedout or rejected also.

Pic of our LAN
[image]

All of the websites used to be view-able in Safari on the Macs, but sometime in the last few months they quit loading. The only really big change we've had is the installation of a new router (a Mikrotik that's a little tough to navigate). Here's what I've tried so far:

- Scanned the web server for malware and viruses, nothing bad reported, no website proxy changes, etc.
- Removed all cookies, etc. from Safari and reloaded website, no luck
- Installed Chrome to see if it was just a Safari problem, same errors but slightly different message ("ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE")
- Checked to see that the router/DNS entries in networking settings of the Macs were configured well to the new Mikrotik (but again, not an expert on the Mikrotik end)
- OS X Server Websites dashboard says that all websites are available on local network (green dashboard lights)
- The webserver's default website (with the cute "Welcome" pic) IS accessible.
- Checked the permissions on the website folders to ensure that _www permissions are good, etc. (again the WordPress websites work externally but not internally on just Mac machines, except for the OS X default website)
- Checked apache access and error logs on the web server. Nothing showing up there - the attempt to access the website isn't even listed.

My guess is that there is something about the new Mikrotik router that is not allowing the Macs (based on how they're all configured) to see the locally hosted websites. But it could be a variety of other things too... I'd really appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: How do you access the WordPress website from the Macs? With the hostname/alias (e.g. www.example.com) or the IP-address? Are the Macs, the WordPress host and the Windows clients all in the same network (e.g. 192.168.0.0/24)? Split-brain DNS set-up? A .local tld internally?

Comment: The problem is with your Macs on the LAN, nowhere else.  What you have to do now is see what the differences are between the Macs and the PC's.  Get the network settings of a PC and a Mac and let's compare them.

Comment: Thanks! @klanomath, I am using the hostname for our website. If I use the machine's IP address (or the .local address), it just goes to the default "Welcome" site. All machines are on the same network, as you specified. We are a really small office - we don't have Windows Server, and just access the Mac minis for a file server, etc. Each machine has a local name (e.g. mymachine.local) specified, but this has not changed the entire time we've had them, and getting the websites from the Macs used to work earlier this year.

Comment: Thanks! @Allan, I will add a screenshot of the DNS settings on the Mac and the Windows settings to the original post. They look the same to me....hmm. I will put in a call to the guy who configured the new router and see if he thinks it is treating these machines differently. Update coming shortly....

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you configuring the Mac's IP addresses manually where the PC is via DHCP?

Comment: Sure. We have the Macs configured with a static IP address so that our Windows machines can connect to them more reliably (we use one of them as an office file server). Using the IP address seems to be more stable with the various Windows and OSX updates the past four or five years. I did try switching to DHCP on the webserver Mac this am, but it didn't have any immediate impact on whether the websites could be seen internally on the Macs. If you think it would help, I can switch to DHCP and then re-map everyone's drives?

Answer (score 1):

Doh! Okay, my bad for not including the gateway IP in the DNS listing as well as in the "Router" field on the Macs. The DNS listings for all of them now say 192.168.70.1, 75.75.75.75, etc. and the sites are now visible.